# Не могу закрыть remodal кнопкой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, popup

Я использую remodal попапы

1. Вот код попапа

```html
<div class="remodal remodal-product" data-remodal-id="product">
 <button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close" aria-label="Закрыть"></button>
 <div class="row new_aps_zone">
  <div class="zakaz-block-td td top new_aps_block">
   <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="windows-1251" class="footer-box-form" id="order_form">
    <button class="add_rabbit_to_cart">В корзину</button>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

2. Вот код  JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  addProducts();
  function addProducts() {
    $('.add_rabbit_to_cart').on('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('div[data-remodal-id="product"]').remodal().close();
      var form = $('#order_form');
      var color = form.find('input[name=bunny_color]:checked').val();
      $('.add_to_cart[data-rabbit='+ color +']').trigger("click");
    });
  }
});
```

3. Вот что при клике на ".add_rabbit_to_cart" возвращает консоль:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
```

Не могу понять почему ?

Comment: А `.remodal()` тут точно не лишний? Перед close()...

Comment: Если убрать .remodal() - получаю "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).close is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

РЕШЕНО - Заменой на
jQuery('.remodal-close').click();